# Tinymce toggle slidedown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tinymce

If i slidedown the tinymce editor the tinymce iframe inner html is removed. After slide down i can't able to type the tinymce text area.

Code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    div {
        height: 300px;
    }
  </style>

  <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "#mytextarea"
            });

            $('button').click(function() {
            $('div').toggle('slide', { direction: 'down' }, 250);
            })
        }//]]> 

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>TinyMCE Getting Started Guide</h1>
        <textarea id="mytextarea">Congratulations!</textarea>
    </div>
    <button>
    click
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Before slidedown:
[image: before slide down]

After slidedown:
[image: After slidown]

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https:////cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    div {
        height: 300px;
    }
  </style>

  <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){


            $('button').click(function() {
             if (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'mytextarea');
                    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'mytextarea');

                }, 100);
                tinyMCE.get('emailTemplateContent').setContent('');
            } else{
            tinyMCE.EditorManager.init({
                selector: "#mytextarea",
                height: 300,
                    plugins: [
                      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                      'searchreplace visualblocks code',
                      'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
                    ],
                    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
            });
            }
            $('#mytextarea').val('');
            })
        }//]]> 

    </script>


</head>
<body>
<button>
    Click
    </button>
    <div>
        <h1>TinyMCE Getting Started Guide</h1>
        <textarea id="mytextarea">Congratulations!</textarea>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer! So that everyone can comprehend what you have done and why you have eine it. Thanks!

Comment: But slidedown or slideup is not happen.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery slidedown uses `display:none` to "hide" elements when not visible and changes the visibility when the items are to be shown - this will cause issues for TinyMCE because when the element has `display:none` its no longer part of the DOM.  When you perform a slide down to show the contents of the `<div>` the `display:none` is changed to `display:block` and the elements are now part of the DOM.   Effectively each time you slide down/up you are creating and destroying DOM elements.

What you need to do is not `init()` TinyMCE until the `<textarea>` is shown via the slide down process.  When you slide up you need to use the `remove()` API to disconnect TinyMCE ***before*** the slide up happens (e.g. before the `<div>` reverts to `display:none` and the elements are removed from the DOM).

I don't know if you can force jQuery to use `visibility:hidden` as opposed to `display:none` but that would eliminate all of this if that is possible.